# Splashscreen is not visible with Android 12

Tags: c#, android, maui, android-12, android-splashscreen

I join other people that have the same problem with `Android` 12 but I can't find a solution.

I have a `MAUI` project. When I deploy the project on an emulator the splashscreen is visible as you can see in the following screenshot.

[image]

When I test the application on a real device with Android 12, the splashscreen is not visible at all.

I read different posts:

- [[Android] API 31 (Android 12) svg on splashscreen is not showing](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7289)
- [Wordaround](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9794)

but it is still not working at all. All the posts I found were quite old, at least 1 year, and no one has a solution.

### Workaround (not working)

Add a file into your .NET MAUI app with this exact name:

> Platforms\Android\Resources\drawable\maui_splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">
    <item android:drawable="@color/maui_splash_color" />
    <item
        android:width="108dp"
        android:height="108dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:src="@drawable/name_of_your_splash_image"
            android:mipMap="true"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Make sure to use the name of your splash screen image in the place of `name_of_your_splash_image`.

Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There are some known issues about this.

And you can follow them up here: [AppIcons and Splash Screens Do Not Render Correctly on Physical Devices](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9029).

You can also check this issue :[[android] fix MauiSplashScreen on Android 12+](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/8394).