# Splashscreen is not visible with iOS 17

Tags: c#, ios, maui, ios17

As I asked in a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77247800/splashscreen-is-not-visible-with-android-12) for Android, I have a similar problem in the same project for iOS.

When I deploy the app to a simulator for iPhone 17 with iOS 17, the splashscreen is completely black. I saw this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10314) on GitHub but there is not solution.

I added in the `info.plist` this values

```
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>MauiSplash</string>
```

When I open this file in Visual Studio, I can't see this key in the list.

Comment: This could be a caching issue. You can try to clean the project and uninstall and reinstall the app on the physical device or emulator. 
Besides, you can refer to this issue ( [Maui app black screen in iPad](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14421) ) for some solutions to help you solve the problem.

Comment: I would not worry about it, unless the problem shows in test flight.

Comment: Do you have the same issue on your iOS16 devices? In order to reproduce your problem, I need to know what your MAUI version is. Is it NET6 or .NET7 or .NET8? And are you using Xcode15?

Comment: @SeanHe-MSFT I'm migrating the app to NET8 and I can't run the app in a iOS device right now.

Answer (score 0):

I built empty Maui projects using .net7 and .net8 and ran them using iOS 17 simulator. After adding the following code to the .csproj file, the simulators of both projects displayed splash normally:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <EnableCodeSigning>true</EnableCodeSigning>
    <CodesignRequireProvisioningProfile>true</CodesignRequireProvisioningProfile>
    <DisableCodesignVerification>true</DisableCodesignVerification>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Specifically, you can refer to this link: [Enable codesigning by default in the simulator](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/18469)